# common table expression for parent child relationship with total

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

My knowledge on common table expressions is lacking at the moment so any help on this is greatly appreciated.

I have three tables `[Category]`, `[Product]` and `[Mapping]` which defines relationships between Product and Category (one to many). Each Category has a ParentId which specifies its parent Category.

What I want to achieve is a list that includes each row from the Category table as well as the count of products assigned to it and all of its children.

So for example (Category table data)

```
Category ID 1 (ParentID 0) has 1 product
Category ID 2 (ParentID 1) has 2 products
Category ID 3 (ParentID 2) has 3 products
```

The result i'm after is something like this...

```
ID     ParentID     Products
1      0            6
2      1            5
3      2            3
```

Again any help on this would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, assuming that you are using SQL Server 2005+ (since you are talking about CTEs), try this query:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT A.ID, A.ParentID, COUNT(*) Products
    FROM Category A
    INNER JOIN Mapping B
    ON A.ID = B.CategoryID
    GROUP BY A.ID, A.ParentID
), CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.ID, B.ParentID, A.Products
    FROM CTE2 A
    INNER JOIN CTE1 B
    ON A.ParentID = B.ID
)
SELECT ID, ParentID, SUM(Products) Products
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY ID, ParentID
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

You can see an example on this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b333/19). The `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` is there so it iterates as much levels as it can, so you either make sure that your data doesn't loop infinitly or you limit the levels of recursion.

Comment: what is i want list of products inplace of count of producs ?